# Gradle and API Dependency

Tags: java, api, gradle, build, dependencies

I have two separate projects and I don't really know if NoClassDefFoundError can be fixed by using API dependency in build.gradle

In my first project I use this library:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.bcel/bcel
compile group: 'org.apache.bcel', name: 'bcel', version: '6.5.0'
```

And in some methods from this project I throw this exception:

```
throw new AssertionViolatedException("Response validation for " + HeaderValue + "Actual as " + StrActual + " Expected " + StrExpected);
```

If I generate the artifact and I used it in my second project as import using this in build.gradle

```
implementation name: 'Project1'
```

Doing this I get the error:

```
Step failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/bcel/verifier/exc/AssertionViolatedException
```

Can this be fixed by using API dependency in the first project instead of adding the bcel dependency in my second project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IntelliJ you can configure the first project as a [composite build](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-gradle-projects.html#gradle_composite_build).

Otherwise you can publish project1 to mavenLocal and use the [mavenLocal repository](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:case-for-maven-local) in the second project. This would mean that you declare the dependency with the group and version as well.

```
implementation group: 'org.group', name: 'Project1', version: '1.0'
```

The documentation suggests that a [composite build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html#composite_builds) is preferable in this case.

Another option is to make a [multiproject build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) which includes project1 and project2. In this setup project2 would declare a [subproject dependency](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies_between_subprojects.html) on project1.

```
implementation project(':project1')
```

Comment: The first project it's like a Base project where some teams need the Jar file as input. It's correct in this case the composite build? The first project should be some king of agnistic to other projects, I shouldn't specify the project I want to link the first one

Comment: It really depends on if the base project is published somewhere (like nexus) or if it is always compiled locally. If the base project is in the same git repo and compiled locally, for example, then I would go with the multiproject build and import it as a project.

Comment: Yes it's been compiled locally, I will try with multiproject build approach. Thanks!